# Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, search-engine, elastic-map-reduce

I am trying index using below Java code in elastic search..
I gave my machine Ip in the code .It is unable to connect to node.
It is giving error like below :

**Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
        at** org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:219)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:82)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:330)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder.doExecute(IndexRequestBuilder.java:314)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
        at test.test1.main(test1.java:30)

Code I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String json = "{" +         
                    "\"user\":\"AMaresh\"," +         
                    "\"postDate\":\"2014-04-23\"," + 
                    "\"message\":\"trying out Elasticsearch\"" +
                    "}";  


    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("elasticsearch", "elasticsearch").build();
    TransportClient transportClient = new TransportClient(settings);

    Client client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("10.210.51.207",9300));

    IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("Cricket", "cric", "1").setSource(json).execute().actionGet();
    //List<String> matches = response.matches();
    System.out.println(response);
    System.out.println("finished");
```

I have checked ports are open in the machine.

Can anybody help me understanding the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is network or Node.js related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem in mentioning cluster name..  Use lik following

```
    Settings settings =               ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
   .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
```

Hope it helps..!

Answer (score 1):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053586/3827220 to a similar problem, is applicable to the error message you're seeing.

Check to make sure you are using the same major version on the client side and the cluster side.