# elasticserch: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available

Tags: java, elasticsearch, upgrade, spring-data

I have update elasticsearch version from `elasticsearch-0.90.7` to `elasticsearch-1.3.1` and application was working fine in `elasticsearch-0.90.7` but in `elasticsearch-1.3.1` getting below exception:

```
2014-07-31/12:49:22.276 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-4]  ERROR step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing the step
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:219)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.bulk(AbstractClient.java:149)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.bulk(TransportClient.java:354)
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestBuilder.doExecute(BulkRequestBuilder.java:165)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
at com.verisign.rzuingest.batch.RzuFilesIngestionTasklet.execute(Ingestion.groovy:75)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using java client `org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:1.0.0.M1` to interact with elastic search some thing like:

```
ElasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(index)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: has your load increased since you last tested? This error may also come if your ES cluster is under stress during indexing.

Answer (score 2):

> TL;DR 
>   Update spring-data-elasticsearch library as well

Different major Elasticsearch versions have [incompatible transport protocols](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/UABRHL94k4k). It was done to avoid version mismatches in a cluster. You have upgraded your ES to 1.3.1, but your spring data library [uses](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch#note) old version of client so it simply can't find other nodes in a cluster - it doesn't know how to communicate them properly.

Just refer to your library documentation to find necessary version to use with ES 1.3.1 and use it.

Comment: Exactly ! 1.0.0.M1 is on 0.90.x version of elasticsearch, try using latest version 1.1.0.M1.

Comment: 1.0.2.RELEASE  
1.1.0.M1               
1.0.1.RELEASE     
1.0.0.RELEASE                                                                                                                            above spring-data-elasticsearch jar version tried getting same issue.... please can suggest exact supported version for elasticserch1.3.1 version
1.0.0.RC1              
1.0.0.M2 
1.0.0.M1

Comment: AFAIK latest 1.0.2.RELEASE supports ES version 1.1.1, so you probably need to wait when newer version of your library arrives

Comment: Thanks Konstantin V. Salikhov and  Mohsin Husen for your answers….
ElasticSearch-1.1.0   and  
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:1.0.0.RC1'   
Solved my problem...:)